# Android SQLlite Sort with simple query

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

Maybe someone can help me before i lose my mind. I want to sort a SQL database.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COLUM_MAME_1, COLUM_MAME_2, COLUM_MAME_3}, null, null, null, null, COLUM_MAME_3 + " ASC");
```

Q: db.query... manipulates or should manipulate the database? Cause I get no error and nothing happens to the database. If not? is there a simple way to do it?

Roland

Comment: The `query()` method is used to return a `Cursor` that contains cells from your database. It does not manipulate the database however. To update something like row order in response to sorting, you would need to use the `update()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In relational databases, tables do not have a guaranteed order.

To view the rows in a specific order, you must sort them whenever you are querying them.